# How to detect the end of a user's session on website to delete session token

Tags: node.js, database, npm, token, session-cookies

For user's who do not want to be remembered between sessions on my site I generate a temporary session token and send it as a cookie to the client so they are remembered between webpages on my site.

The cookie automatically expires at the end of the session since that is the default, but how can I detect the end of the session server side?

I want to delete the session token at the end of the user's session from my database and then should they log in again I want to generate a new session token.

Comment: Is it really required to store sessions in your server ?? How about generating the session token using an asymmetric encryption (like sha1)  with a known key (like userid or user name) and a salt and may be a time. With each request you can verify the validity of the session token. You need not store and maintain the sessions in your server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "session" concept in "cookie-expires-at-end-of-session" is actually only known on the browser. From wikipedia:

> A session cookie, also known as an in-memory cookie or transient
>   cookie, exists only in temporary memory while the user navigates the
>   website.[13] Web browsers normally delete session cookies when the
>   user closes the browser.

So this might still leave a cookie to linger quite a long time if the user keeps his browser open for days in a row (like me).

One way to achieve what you want is to have the web page send a "heart-beat" to the server, e.g. using `setTimeout` in javascript to access a certain URL every 10 seconds, and passing some unique identification of his "session" (in the sense that you want, not the cookie-session). If that heartbeat stops, you know your web page was closed, or the user surfed away from it etc, and you can immediately clean up your server side state.

More in detail, the "heartbeat URL" would simply maintain a list of active sessions. Each access to that URL would update the time-stamp of last activity of the specified session (e.g. `http://..../heartbeat?id=12345`). That way you have a list of "most recent time stamps" for all active sessions. A separate cleanup thread would then run over that list once in a while to clean up those sessions that haven't been updated in the last (10...) seconds.

For example (using JQuery for the URL access, could do the same with just `XMLHttpRequest`...)

```
<script>
function heartBeat() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $.get("heartBeat?id="+mySessionId, function( data ) {
         // you may want to add sanity checks here, e.g. what with invalid session ids?
         heartBeat();   // next call to heartBeat after OK response
      }
    }, 10000);
}
heartBeat();  // first call to heartBeat
</script>
```

This will call your server URL every 10 seconds (plus your server response delay).